# Is there any code to read MS Office PPT on Android?

Tags: android, apache, ms-office, apache-poi

I'm looking for code to read MS Office PPT on Android, is there anyone interested in sharing the code?

Comment: Maybe http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/ is of interest, if you are processing pptx, not binary .ppt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at **Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents**

The Apache POI Project's mission is to create and maintain Java APIs for manipulating various file formats based upon the Office Open XML standards (OOXML) and Microsoft's OLE 2 Compound Document format (OLE2). In short, you can read and write MS Excel files using Java. In addition, you can read and write MS Word and MS PowerPoint files using Java.

http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

I found an useful Url here:
   http://code.google.com/p/display-msoffice-docs-android-with-apache-poi/source/checkout

Answer (score 1):

there are some trial library about Ms-office on Android http://code.google.com/p/android-office-demo/downloads/list